# Mask generated internet network traffic

Tags: linux, networking

I'm studying Linux system and something networking.
Now I'm trying to understand whether there is a way to mask / fake / spoof the traffic (uploaded and downloaded bytes) that comes from my `Linux Mint 17.3` computer to a router? 
For example I could need to fake the amout of data I have generated while surfing on the internet, for security reason.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fake", like sending extra bogus traffic for some reason? There is no fake data, data is data, but bogus data is possible but I don't understand your reasoning, what possible security purpose could there be? That and sending bogus data could trip your ISP's router or firewall rules getting you banned for TOS violations.

Comment: I mean like sending less data than what I have actually sent.

Comment: as measured from what point in the network? I'm inclined to say "no" flat out, but where is the adversary measuring, and do you have control of the device they measure from?

Comment: @FrankThomas, yes I have control of the device they measure from. I just need to test the situation when a linux user sends less data than what he has actually done. So I'd like to do something on my linux machine to do that test.